# Best way to think about the formalizatoin of exponential generating functions\generating function

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, generating-functions

When talking about say exponential generating functions, there are a couple ways to think of it that I'm aware of.

The first is to think about it as formal series, denote this way by (1).

The latter is to think of it as analytic functions over some disk (if there is such disk with radius larger than 0, denoted by way (2).

The sweet thing about (2), when we assume all functions we're dealing with at the moment converge in a disk of radius more than 0 is that we can do freely without worry: we can take derivatives, multiply and add as we wish, and the result will be what we want because of the uniqueness of expansion as power series.

The disadvantage of (2) is clear, sometimes we are counting objects who's coefficients grow too large. This is where (1) has a benefit. However, the problem with (1) is that I don't feel comfortable regarding some things: Say we have this e.g.f, $F(x)$, and we have determined that $F(x)=1+xF(x)^2$ (as formal power series, with the operations defined on formal sums), in examples I see we then solve the function not in a formal sense, like here they'd say $F(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$, and then find the taylor expansion and thereby determine the coefficients. There's no way this is possible by (1), the case must be that they assume apriori that for those power series there will a good radius of convergence and like with ODE's, if it works perfect, that's the thinking right?

I'm not completly satisfied with this, what if we want to solve another functional equation as above but in which case the coefficients grow too fast for there to be a radius of convergance? How would we overcome it? Or come to tihnk of it, is there a way to say that the mere existence of the functional equations assures us the coefficients don't grow too fast? I think I'm digging too deep at something that should be simpler.

Comment: One thing: I am a little puzzled by the example you have taken because it is the OGF (ordinary generating function) for Catalan numbers ((http://geometryatlas.com/entries/43) btw very nicely illustrated article) and not the EGF (exponential generating function) as in your title (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_.28EGF.29)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, they happen to concide in that case (I'm brining the example from https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf ). If you prefer, one can also look at the functional equation for unordered trees in which they differ, which can be found here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/trees.pdf

Comment: Thus my question is : do you want to refer to **any type** of generating function (OGF, EGF, ...) , knowing that you address the issue of convergence of the correponding function ? A first answer is that usually, issues of convergence are not in the foreground : most computations are done in a formal approach (in a clean mathematical way) in R[[X]].

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't exactly understand your question, but I'd be happy to hear a good explanation for all types of generating functions (I assume any explanation will work for both). How do you determine $F(x)$ in $R[x]$ as above (of course I don't want an answer that says induction on the coeffiicents or something, but rather how you prove that we can solve the equations as if we have a real functions)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "there's no way this is possible by (1)." What step are you uncomfortable with in solving for $F(x)$ as a formal power series?

Comment: [ctd] But I have to moderate what I just said: There are many cases where deep properties of the analytical OGF, EGF, etc. are used (not only convergence radii...); you probably know the marvelous book "Analytic Combinatorics" by Flageolet and Sedgewick (Cambridge ed.) containing a wealth of methods...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe I'm misunderstanding, how do solve in formal power series the equation $0=1-F(x)+xF(x)^2$? If I brought a bad example, then another one that occurs is (after we define on formal power series derivative as usual) that we solve an ODE of some on the function, which again I don't see how can be done via working only with formal sums.

Comment: You use the quadratic formula. The proof of the quadratic formula only involves operations that continue to make sense on formal power series (the least obvious of which is taking square roots, but this can be done formally, because $(1 + x)^{1/2}$ itself is a formal power series).

Comment: I just read your answer posted 5 min. ago : we have to work in the ring of formal power series R[[X]] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series), not only R[x]. the fact that two formal power series are identical as long as their coefficients are the same should be enough, no ? But maybe I haven't understood what was really your question ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess that works, just making sure, is this the right way to think about this (in formal power series)? What about solving ODE's?

Comment: @JeanMarie enough for what? I'm asking what is the best way to think about e.g.f, and if there is a way to avoid thinking about as in (2) when we find one of them solves a equation (which we can as Quaochu pointed out) or an ODE

Comment: You can also ask questions about solving ODEs entirely in the setting of formal power series, since you can take derivatives (and integrals) formally. I'm still not sure what exactly your question is here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes we can get ODE equations, but when solving them we pretend they're real functions. For example, if I was solving $F'(x)=-F(x)^2$, what I would do is guess that the solution has coefficients not growing so fast, so I can view it as a real function, then solve it as a seperable ODE, and eventually determine its taylor coefficients (Since I know there is a unique one that works). Would you have another way via only formal power series (beyond guessing the solution)?

Comment: @Andy: yes, you can just prove that calculus works the same way on formal power series as it does on functions (it's actually easier to do this than to prove that calculus works on functions). As with the quadratic formula, every manipulation you would use to solve this as a separable ODE can be proven to make sense on formal power series (although at various points you might need to work with formal Laurent series, which form a field; this is not a problem).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, that answers my question I guess. I admit that's a bit disappointing, I hoped there would be more to it, but I understand what's going on better. If you write it out I'll accept as an answer.